# tree derived from monad is itself a monad

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

I have constructed a functor from a monad that appears (based on computer experiments to test the monad laws) to also have monad properties but I am having trouble proving it.

Here is the idea: M[A] is a monad, and Either[A.B] is the usual "or" bifunctor.

Let N[A] = M[Either[A, N[A]]]
It's a recursive definition so these M-trees could be finite or infinite.
I specify that they are finite only.

Now we can define map, unit and join transformations of the correct type signature

N(f) = M( bimap(f, N(f)))
and so on.

I have managed to prove, with brute force techniques, that N is a functor and unit is a natural transformation in the appropriate way.
However, I am having difficulty with the laws dealing with the join, because the definitions of map and join are recursive, and so my proofs go around in circles.

Is there a particular mathematical technique for proving a functor is a monad when it is defined recursively?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. Is $M$ a monad on $Set$? What is the "usual 'or' bifunctor" -- is it disjoint sum? Is $N(A)$ supposed to be an initial algebra of the endofunctor $X \mapsto M[\text{Either}[A, X]]$?

Comment: M is any monad, but my usecase comes from functional programming, so I am thinking in terms of monads on types.

Either[A,B] is the functional programming way of representing the coproduct (i.e. disjoint sum) of A and B.

N is an endofunctor constructed by composition.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that what you construct here is known in the functional programming community as [the *resumption* monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-resumption). In general, given an endofunctor $F$ and a monad $M$, the functor part of the resumption monad $R^{F,M}$ is given as

$$R^{F,M} A = \mu X. M(FX+A),$$

where $\mu X. G X$ is the carrier of the initial $G$-algebra for an endofunctor $G$. A bit nicer way to specify this monad is

$$R^{F,M} A = M (FM)^*A,$$

where $(FM)^*$ is the free monad generated by the composition of endofunctors $F$ and $M$. This gives you automatically that $R^{F,M}$ is an endofunctor.

Your construction is obtained for $F = \mathrm{Id}$, that is the identity endofunctor.

The monadic structure for $R^{F,M}$ can be obtained via a distributive law $(FM)^*M \rightarrow M(FM)^*$ and the construction was introduced by Hyland, Plotkin, and Power in  ["Combining effects: Sum and tensor"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397506002659), Theorem 4.

The construction in the "infinite case" was given by me and J.Gibbons in ["The Coinductive Resumption Monad"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066114000826), Theorem 3.8.

If you are interested in general methods of constructing monadic structure for endofunctors given by similar fixed points, try Uustalu's ["Generalizing substitution"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.4368).